# Html5 video only plays once in firefox

Tags: django, firefox, video, amazon-s3, html5-video

I'm loading an MP4 from Amazon S3 into a html5 video tag dynamically with django. It plays fine in most browsers but in Firefox it only plays the first time the browser is opened but not after the page is reloaded. The video tags and source are still set correctly but the video does not load. There's no error in the console, it seems simply not to GET the video file.

The content type is set to MP4 on S3 so I believe the mime type should be set properly.

I can only think that Firefox is trying to to cache the video and causing some issue, but I've tried clearing the cache but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

I'm stumped, has anyone come across this issue before and can help? Thanks

Comment: You need to provide a copy of your code to reference.